# PHP Displaying PHP foreach values when some values have a space between two words coming from the DB

Tags: php, arrays, object, foreach

**This question was closed which is ok Take a look at the suggested questions. I would not have known to search what those are titled so dont just click away!.**

I am not sure how to work with PHP `foreach` when the values it is pulling have a space in them inside the database.

Example - in the DB the following value exists and object in an array like - Number One. So I first tried:

```
foreach ($type as $value){
$value->Number One
};
echo $value->Number One
```

This above produced a string error.

I followed by using a non breaking space. `Number&nbsp;One` .
When I use this, all I get is a value of '00' which is incorrect. The value is actually '1'. So how do you handle an object in an array when there is a space in the object name as it comes from the DB?

Comment: `$value->{'Number One'};`

Comment: That is the hope which is why I posted the above. I think sometimes people just see a closed question and move on without reading or clicking onto the better one

Comment: you don't need to worry about the question being closed as a duplicate; there are many questions on the site which are hard to find without knowing the exact phrase to search for (although searching on google tends to yield far better results than stackoverflow search). Well written duplicates frequently get left on the site because they are easier to search for. Anyway, it won't have any effect on your use of the site.

Comment: It would be better though if you removed the commentary, it doesn't really add anything to the question and may discourage users from reading it and seeing that it matches their problem.

Comment: 'sometimes I think people here forget non-expert programmers sometimes dont know what to search'—having your question closed as a duplicate isn't a bad thing. In fact it's a _good_ thing: it points you to one or more useful questions, ideally each with at least one helpful answer. And it helps future users who might search for terminology that you use do the same.

Comment: until I am then blocked from asking questions for a day or two sure